# react keyword extends doesnt pick up

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I've been trying to learn webpack for a while now, it doesnt seem to have problems with images or css...just react, i get the following error message. It doesnt recognize it... 
I have tried to read and fix it for a long while now so, any help will be greatly appreciated will cooperate in helping others when im not a newbie.

In my react page

```
const img = require('./dog.jpeg');
require('./style.css');
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Page extends React.Component () {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <p>A silly complicated way to show an HTML document</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In my webpack.common.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry:{
    app: './src/index.js',

  },
  plugins : [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['../dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Web w react, express webpack dev n prod',

    })
  ],
  output : {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist')
  },
  module : {
    rules:[
      // {
      //     test: /\.js$/,
      //     loader: 'babel-loader',
      //     exclude: /node_modules/,
      //     query: {presets: ['es2015']}
      //   },
        {
        test: /\.(jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/react']
          }
        }
      },
        // {
        //   test: /\.jsx$/,
        //   loader:'babel-loader',
        //   query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}
        // },
      {
        test:/\.(css|scss)$/,
        use:['style-loader', 'css-loader','sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
              fallback: 'file-loader'
            }
          }
        ]
}
    ]
  }
}
```

[error message that comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Tkn.png)
All the code is on this link
 [Link to this on Github](https://github.com/10Nopalitos/webpack-attempt2)

Comment: What is the file extension on the file giving you an error? If it is `.js`, that is likely the problem. Your configuration only applies the babel loader to `.jsx` files.

Comment: That's completely correct, Thank you very much, its funny how after look at the screen for so long i overlook things. Where do i click to give you points?

Comment: I deleted my answer when I realized you never said if your file was `js` or not. I undeleted it :) you can approve it there... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your module loader rules. The only one of those rules that would remotely file load the js files is here:

```
  {
    test: /\.(jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/react']
      }
    }
  },
```

now look at `test: /\.(jsx)$/`. This lets web pack know which files to load with the given configuration defined in the object. The file you mentioned with the error is a `.js` file. If you want that to be loaded with the same configuration, you'll need to modify the `test` to `test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,`. So it should look like this.

```
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/react']
      }
    }
  },
```

I haven't looked into this too deeply... so please lmk if that fixes your issue. good luck!

Comment: Honestly i still get an error message on my console and nothing loads up ummm I really wish i had an idea on what it could be, a similar post on overflow didnt get answered but acomment  said it could be dependencies, i reinstalled the ones on the example i partially followed and pushed it to git hub ...